# Transformer fuses for Primary and Secondary

Tags: transformer, fuses

Good afternoon, I hope that you are all well not withstanding COVID-19.

I have a 230/24v 250VA Transformer which is being used to power 4 x motors drawing a maximum of 20.3 Watts each.

I would like to know what amperage of fuse to use for primary and secondary and whether or not they need to be slow blow?

The data sheet for the transformer can be found here:
https://media.automation24.com/datasheet/en/86345_Data%20Sheet_en.pdf

Many thanks in advance and stay well.

Comment: What specifically are the fuses intended to protect?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I would have though that it would be to protect the transformer's primary windings (in the event of an internal short) and the secondary windings in the event of an internal short, or a short in one of the motors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is only drawing about 3.4A maximum assuming your accounting for start-up current, so if your goal is to protect the motors, a 4 or 5A fuse, if your protecting the transformer, a 10A fuse on the secondary, slow blow is more needed when both the motor maximum and the transformer maximum are close, e.g. all 4 motors spinning up at the same time, the transformer under say a 50% overload will not burn out faster than the fuse, so a slow fuse is selected for the short spinup period.

Input fuse about 2A conventional.

Comment: Many thanks for youR answer. Just to confirm - you don't advise using a slow blow for this application?

Comment: Not unless you forgot about the motors startup current, if your total power consumption per motor includes that, then any time above that power amount is unlikely, as such no need for slow blow. Its for cases where say the motors will draw 15A for 3-5 seconds while starting, but you want to protect the transformer against shorts above 10A, here a slow blow would be needed.

Comment: Thanks again Reroute.

Answer (score 1):

```
What specifically are the fuses intended to protect? – Andy aka
```

> *I'm no expert, but I would have though that it would be to protect the
>   transformer's primary windings (in the event of an internal short)*

No, you should be trying to protect the infra-structure wiring that feeds the transformer in case the transformer fails short circuit and melts the infra-structure wiring causing a fire and lots of damage, cost and risk. You can use a slow blow fuse.

So, you need to understand what the building/site wiring is rated at and choose a fuse of suitable value. You can't protect the transformer against itself failing - if it fails it's trash and no amount of fusing is going to make it anything less than trash.

And, by the same token, the transformer and wiring to the motors are the "new" infra-structure that need to be protected from the motors going short circuit and drawing too much current. If you deem the transformer to be the weak link in that new infra-structure then you could use a thermal fuse that blows when the transformer gets too warm or just a regular slow blow fuse.

```
In all situations of using a fuse, the fuse is to protect infra-structure.
```

Comment: I follow a variation on that, fuse for the lower, the maximum expected use case + some margin, or the infrastructure, If I have wire that can handle 100A, but things have gone bad at 20A, I would be selecting the 20A fuse.

Comment: Fusing for use_case+margin OR infrastructure is NOT protecting the infrastructure in the even that the use_case+margin exceeds the rating for the infrastructure. Be careful here what you recommend.

Comment: "Fuse for the lower" as in, which ever is the smaller value.

Comment: This is not really correct.  The building wiring is protected by the _building circuit's_ fuse/breaker.  Device fuses are not intended for that.  Primary and secondary fuses also serve two different purposes.  Primary fuses protect (upstream) against a short occurring in the transformer.  Secondary fuses protect (the transformer coils) against being overloaded.  In a mains-AC connected device, the primary fuse is intended to protect _the socket and power cord,_ nothing else.  Therefore, you only need to care about what those can handle (typically 15A in the US) when limiting the max value.

Comment: @Foogod which part of my answer are you having problems with specifically?

Comment: @Andyaka Well, primarily these parts: (a) "you need to understand what the building/site wiring is rated at" (thiis is just plain wrong, you do not need to care about this at all), (b) your immediate response of "No", suggesting that the commenter's answer was wrong (which it wasn't, just maybe incomplete), and also (c) "In all situations of using a fuse, the fuse is to protect infra-structure." (This is also wrong.  Device fuses are usually included to protect components _within or attached to the device._  The infrastructure should already have its own separate protection measures.)

Comment: Note, BTW, that we are clearly here talking about choosing fuses to be included in the design of a _device,_ not circuit breakers/etc which are part of the electrical infrastructure.  This is pretty clear because the user is asking about "fuses" (not breakers), and "primary and secondary" fuses at that, and is describing a low-voltage step-down transformer (to 24V) for driving motors, which is obviously part of a motor control circuit, not a (building) infrastructure component.

Comment: @Foogod why don't you make an answer and, in that answer you can make your objections to my answer perfectly clear. Take your time; do a good job on this and maybe I'll be able to respond other than to say I disagree. Don't forget to explicitly explain hw a fuse can protect an internal component and, to what it is being protected from.

Comment: @Andyaka Because that is not how StackExchange works.  Answers are for answering the original question, not responding to other answers or comments.